# User/browser fingerprinting without cookies

Tags: authentication, browser, cookies, post, fingerprint

I'm sure that many of you have heard about this: http://panopticlick.eff.org/

It's a way to form a somewhat unique fingerprint of a web site visitor based on information about their browser, fonts, plugins, etc...

Does anyone know of a library (python!?) to do this?

I'd like to allow for visitors to vote on a poll without having to have an account...

Answer (score 1):

You could get jQuery to send that data to your server, and garner the rest on receipt of that request from HTTP headers.

Create a checksum, bish-bash-bosh done.

**warning** as much of that information is JS provided (this also applies to the user agent) it is *very* easily manipulated. If you have a single hash, I only have to change one small value (like browser version) to get a new vote.

Sounds dangerous ... why not just **use logins like everyone else**, it's easy with OpenID nowadays.

Comment: I want to provide for a very "lightweight" user experience.  I don't need users for anything else and I think the ability to vote without logging in will increase participation.  Do you know if jQuery can get the fonts/plugins?

Comment: See: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/868406-classid-get-list-installed-fonts

Comment: this fingerprint is usefull for "vote" systems or simple "polls".